# Check with which template parameter a class was instantiated (compile time)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, template-specialization

I try to write a metafunction `type_par_same_as` that selects `true_type` whenever the template parameter(s) of a class match the given types:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:76,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:76,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:76,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:76,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctemplate+%3Ctypename...%3E+class+Template,+typename+T%3E%0Astruct+type_par_same_as_impl+:+std::false_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctemplate+%3Ctypename...%3E+class+Template,+typename...+Args%3E%0Astruct+type_par_same_as_impl%3CTemplate%3CArgs...%3E,+Args...%3E+:+std::true_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctemplate+%3Ctypename...%3E+class+Template,+typename...+Args%3E%0Aconcept+type_par_same_as+%3D+type_par_same_as_impl%3CTemplate,+Args...%3E::value%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+vint%3B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::string%3E+vstring%3B%0A++++if+constexpr+(type_par_same_as%3Cdecltype(vint),+int%3E)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Vector+instantiated+with+type+int!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.804757760371345,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.19524223962866,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

template <template <typename...> class Template, typename T>
struct type_par_same_as_impl : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args>
struct type_par_same_as_impl<Template<Args...>, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args>
concept type_par_same_as = type_par_same_as_impl<Template, Args...>::value;

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> vint;
    std::vector<std::string> vstring;
    if constexpr (type_par_same_as<decltype(vint), int>) {
        printf("Vector instantiated with type int!\n");
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
<source>:11:56: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class ...> class Template, class T> struct type_par_same_as_impl'
   11 | struct type_par_same_as_impl<Template<Args...>, Args...> : std::true_type {};
      |                                                        ^
<source>:11:56: note:   expected a class template, got 'Template<Args ...>'
```

My approach was that a raw template template parameter just takes in any specialization of a template, say e.g. `std::vector` (without type). Then I SFINAE-out class types that don't match the template specialization Template<Args...> (e.g. `std::vector<int>` in case int was given as `Args`) and I should receive `true_type` for all class types where this can be done. But my logic seems to be off at some point. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: So many issues. One of them, `std::vector<>` has more than one type argument, so it won't work. Other, don't pass `Template<Args...>` but `Template`; but even than, it's not more specialized.

Comment: `std::vector` has more than 1 template argument

Comment: @lorro True I forgot the allocator! Is there a way I can check just one of the template parameters?

Comment: @glades Yes, leave the other unbound (add another parameter pack)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to make it compile:

```
template <class Template, typename... T>
struct type_par_same_as_impl : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args>
struct type_par_same_as_impl<Template<Args...>, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template <class Template, typename... Args>
concept type_par_same_as = type_par_same_as_impl<Template, Args...>::value;
```

But it won't work with your test case as `std::vector<int>` is really `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>` and you're passing only the `int` of the two. So you need:

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<int> vint;
    std::vector<std::string> vstring;
    if constexpr (type_par_same_as<decltype(vint), int, std::allocator<int>>) {
        printf("Vector instantiated with type int!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @glades You need `typename... T` in the first part as well. (fixed)

Comment: Thanks made some adaptions for case with first template parameter but now I think it's too greedy: https://godbolt.org/z/sE1h9oTYa

Comment: @glades `if constexpr (first_targ_same_as<decltype(vint), int, std::allocator<int>>) {` - or you need to implement the additional arg pack

Comment: Got it to work like I intended :) https://godbolt.org/z/W6dqKrnad. Maybe you can add this to the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The base (`false_type`) specialization can have simpler arguments, `template<class...>` is sufficient.

Comment: I would also recommend `static_assert` instead of `if constexpr`, but that's on OP, not you :-)

Answer (score 2):

This can work as originally intended, if, expanding on [lorro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74732307), `Args...` are placed in a [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) so they're only deduced from the explicitly passed template parameters, and not the parameters which which `std::vector` is instantiated, by making use of [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename Template, typename... Args>
struct type_par_same_as_impl : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> typename Template, typename... Args>
struct type_par_same_as_impl<Template<std::type_identity_t<Args>...>, Args...>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename Template, typename... Args>
concept type_par_same_as = type_par_same_as_impl<Template, Args...>::value;

static_assert(type_par_same_as<std::vector<int>, int, std::allocator<int>>);
static_assert(type_par_same_as<std::vector<int>, int>);
static_assert(not type_par_same_as<std::vector<int>, float>);
```

[Try it on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cq9qfG9sM)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a solution that I found just now which is possibly a bit more versatile.

Instead of comparing the first template parameter one might as well extract the nth template parameter and use the idiomatic `std::is_same<U,T>` to compare it. This way the user has the freedom to choose which template parameter is actually compared:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:36,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:36,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Cstd::size_t,+typename%3E%0Astruct+nth_targ_of%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cstd::size_t+N,+template+%3Ctypename...%3E+class+Template,+typename...+Args%3E%0Astruct+nth_targ_of%3CN,+Template%3CArgs...%3E%3E+:+std::tuple_element%3CN,+std::tuple%3CArgs...%3E%3E+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cstd::size_t+N,+typename+T%3E%0Ausing+nth_targ_of_t+%3D+nth_targ_of%3CN,+T%3E::type%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+vint%3B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::string%3E+vstring%3B%0A++++if+constexpr(std::same_as%3Cnth_targ_of_t%3C0,+decltype(vint)%3E,+int%3E)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Vector+instantiated+with+type+int!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++if+constexpr(std::same_as%3Cnth_targ_of_t%3C0,+decltype(vstring)%3E,+std::string%3E)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Vector+instantiated+with+type+string!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.804757760371345,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.19524223962866,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdio>

template<std::size_t, typename>
struct nth_targ_of;

template<std::size_t N, template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args>
struct nth_targ_of<N, Template<Args...>> : std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>> {};

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
using nth_targ_of_t = nth_targ_of<N, T>::type;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vint;
    std::vector<std::string> vstring;
    if constexpr(std::same_as<nth_targ_of_t<0, decltype(vint)>, int>) {
        printf("Vector instantiated with type int!\n");
    }
    if constexpr(std::same_as<nth_targ_of_t<0, decltype(vstring)>, std::string>) {
        printf("Vector instantiated with type string!\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Vector instantiated with type int!
Vector instantiated with type string!
```

Comment: You could simplify this by changing the definition of the partial specialization to `struct nth_targ_of<N, Template<Args...>> : std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>> {};` Also the base template declaration of `nth_targ_of` should just have `typename` instead of `typename...`, the pack is unnecessary.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts True that thanks, updated